# Method refactor in Intellij Idea and/or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, methods, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have many classes (45 at least). Each one has its own method to validate something that is repeated in all the classes, so I have the code repeated in all those classes. I'd like to have one method and call it from all the classes.

If have the following code to know if a mobile device is connecting to the server

```
private boolean isMobileDevice(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
    return userAgent.indexOf("Windows CE") != -1;
}
```

As said before, This method is repeated in many classes

Is it possible in Intellij Idea and/or Eclipse to do that refactor? and How can I perform that refactor?

Comment: Would it be possible to look at some sample code ?

Comment: Of course it'd be possible, I added my repeated function to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isMobileDevice(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
        return userAgent.indexOf("Windows CE") != -1;
}
```

I bet that my Eclipse will warn me that this method can be declared as `static`, because it does not use any fields of enclosing class - such method should be declared as static to let you know that it is not essentially needed in enclosing class, and if there will be a reason (having 45 methods in place of one is THE REASON) you can move it to some other class, and just call it as public or package method.

EDIT: It did: `The method isMobileDevice(HttpServletRequest) from the type Test can be declared as static`:

So:

Copy it to some other class, make it `public static boolean isMobileDevice(HttpServletRequest request)` and use in every classes where it was `private boolean`.

That's all, but I don't see and way to make it with automatic refactor.

Answer (score 0):

With Intellij you could try `"Refactor" > "Find and Replace Code Duplicates..."`.
It will replace the duplicate code by a static function.